# Node.js file to run a local server with access-control-allow-origin

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have an html file that has resources in it's directory

(example file tree)

```
index.html
imgs
  >img1.jpg
  >img2.jpg
  >img3.jpg
js
  >js1.js
  >js2.js
```

How do I run a node.js server that will allow me to view the HTML file, as well as allow me to access certain websites with the access-control-allow-origin *

I am unfamiliar with node, so the simpler, the better!

Extra: does not necessarily have to be node, just a server that will allow access control

Comment: https://github.com/zeit/serve

Comment: On this site, you would typically do some of your own research into the options, write some code and then post here when you got stuck on something and include the code you have so far.  This site isn't very good for beginning tutorials that are merely copies of things already on the web.  What have you researched so far?  What have you done so far?    Have you built a basic nodejs server that you can then start adding features to?  There are literally thousands of tutorials on the web to start with.

Comment: your server (node.js server in this case) has no bearing on other *certain websites*. If they allow CORS through access-control-allow-origin, then good, but your server has no control over what someone elses server sends

Comment: @Will for this case even if I'm lazy or cannot install nginx I'll do simple express app and serve it. Few lines of code and no rocket science. Just `app.js` file and `public` folder with static files makes my day. `package.json` and `node_modules` are de-facto elements of any nodejs app (unless You install packages globally and if don't init an app).

Comment: @JaromandaX I think Kore just wants to play with frontend stuff and just needs simple web server that may be extended with extra features. And to avoid CORS problems with browser he asked for example.

Comment: @num8er - I interpreted the question differently :p

Comment: @JaromandaX haha (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since You're learning and starting from scratch so it's preferred to learn how it's done than installing `supper-pupper swiss knife toolset` that will hide the logic from You and make You boring lazy developer.

If You just want to achieve quick result and don't want to learn - You may use [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) package that will do what You need.

But if You're learning nodejs from zero to hero so read my answer.

It's better to do simple things.

Let's go (:

Create some folder and inside of it do following commands in terminal (or `cmd` in windows os):

1) Init app:

```
npm init
```

2) Install `express` module:

```
npm i --save express
```

3) Install `cors` module/middleware:

```
npm i --save cors
```

4) Create `public` folder and put Your html files there

5) Create `app.js` file in sibling folder with `public`:

```
"use strict";

const
  express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors()); // attach cors middleware (must be set before of most route handlers to populate appropriate headers to response context)
app.use('/', express.static('public'));
app.listen(8080, () => console.log('APP STARTED'));
```

6) Run it: `node app.js`

7) Open in browser: http://127.0.0.1:8080

for more stuff search in YouTube for `nodejs express tutorials`, `nodejs mean stack tutorials` and etc. (:

Comment: After doing this, i get this error still:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Kore fixed, check my updated answer. (screenshot: http://joxi.ru/823gg6UJge8b2O)

Answer (score 1):

For a quick resolution it can also be checked, the Chrome Web server app, for creating local server allowing access to the local files over localhost server.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb